# Django: filter a query with an object attribute

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build a filter depending on if an object attribute is empty or not.

Below my 2 class tables:

```
Buy model
id   buy_price sell_price
10   15        50
20   30        110
30   80        250

Sell model
item buyer*
10   Ana

*This is an OneToOneField(Buy)
```

What I really need is to query a sum of the `buy_price` and `sell_price` that are NOT listed in Sell model (my_buy_object.sell.buyer == '')

I tryied the code below but it's not working properly:

```
buys = Buy.objects.order_by('-id')
sum_price = [buy.buy_price for buy in buys if buy.sell.buyer == '']
sum_price = sum(sum_price)
```

The correct answer for this code should be `sum_buy_price: 110` and `sum_sell_price: 360`

Thank you!

EDIT: added the models:

```
class Buy(models.Model):
   category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   image = models.FileField()
   date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
   buy_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
   sell_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)

   def __str__(self):
       return f'{self.id}'

class Sell(models.Model):
   item = models.OneToOneField(Buy, related_name='sell', 
   on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
   discount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
   total_paid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
   buyer = models.ForeignKey(Buyer, related_name='sell', 
   on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   def __str__(self):
       return f'{self.buyer}'
```

Comment: can you add your models here ?

Comment: Done, I've just added the models!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter empty related fields, use [**`isnull`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-isnull) filter

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Buy.objects.filter(sell__buyer__isnull=True
                   ).aggregate(sum_buy_price=Sum('buy_price'),
                               sum_sell_price=Sum('sell_price'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It was exactly what I was expecting!